# Docker multiple independent versions of the same docker-compose app on same VPS

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, apache2, devops

I am trying to build a structure like this:

```
application-1/
├── docker/
│     ├── apache2
│     ├── php
│     ├── docker-compose.yml
├── src/
└── other-framework-files/

application-2/
├── docker/
│     ├── apache2
│     ├── php
│     ├── docker-compose.yml
├── src/
└── other-framework-files/
```

Where each application is a completely independent instance of the same code. I want to get to the point where I can have my application spawn up twice and where I can develop on two "boxes" independently.

This structure works fine for one instance.

Let's just say that in my folder I have only one app which I run with:

```
cd application-1/
docker-compose up -d
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: ./php/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: webapp
    image: php:7.4.2-fpm-alpine
    volumes:
      - ../:/srv/app
  apache2:
    build:
      network: host
      context: ./apache2/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: apache2
    image: httpd:2.4.39-alpine
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ../:/srv/app
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 13306:3306
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql:cached
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: content
      MYSQL_USER: content
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: content
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:5.0.6-alpine
    ports:
      - 16379:6379
    volumes:
      - redis:/data:cached

volumes:
  mysql:
    driver: local
  redis:
    driver: local
```

This WORKS perfectly fine for one instance of the app.

When I go to

```
http://123.123.123:8080 (my Digital Ocean droplet)
```

I can see my website and it's all good.

However, if I want to copy that over to application 2 and run it from there I can't get that to work. For the second application I have tried to change the name of all the containers and I also changed ports like this:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  webapp2:
    build:
      context: ./php/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: webapp2
    image: php:7.4.2-fpm-alpine
    volumes:
      - ../:/srv/app
  apache2-2:
    build:
      network: host
      context: ./apache2/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: apache2-2
    image: httpd:2.4.39-alpine
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    volumes:
      - ../:/srv/app
  mysql2:
    container_name: mysql2
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 13309:3306
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql:cached
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: content
      MYSQL_USER: content
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: content
  redis2:
    container_name: redis2
    image: redis:5.0.6-alpine
    ports:
      - 16380:6379
    volumes:
      - redis:/data:cached

volumes:
  mysql2:
    driver: local
  redis2:
    driver: local
```

By doing this I was hoping I could get two COMPLETELY independent multi-container composer apps. So that two developers could work separately on the same app.

But when I try to access it like this

```
http://123.123.123:8081
```

It just doesn't load anything. Says the website is unavailable. It doesn't hit apache or anything. It just doesn't work.

Would anyone be able to point me into the right direction here? I do not need any fancy solutions. It is just for the development, just to get started and then I can try to tweak stuff.

UPDATE:

This is my apache2 config. I have changed webapp to webapp2 for second instance.

```
LoadModule deflate_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.content.local
    ServerAlias content.local
    # Proxy .php requests to port 9000 of the php-fpm container
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://webapp:9000/srv/app/public/$1
    DocumentRoot /srv/app/public
    <Directory /srv/app/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Send apache logs to stdout and stderr
    CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 common
    ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you double-check that all of the directory names are correct (`src` vs. `srv`, and so on)?  In particular if both `docker-compose.yml` files are in directories named `docker` this makes a difference.

Comment: @DavidMaze - hm, /srv/app is define in my docker file as: `WORKDIR /srv/app/`. This is the path where `application1` and `application2` folder live. And in these folders I have my symfony application. Do you think I did something wrong here? Setup works fine for port 8080 but doesn't work for 8081. am I even right in thinking that this might work like that? I also have apache proxy config but I updated container name in there as well.

Comment: @DavidMaze - I did everything from scratch on my Mac instead VPS and it works fine. The only new change I made to this is networks. I have added networks but I am not sure if this is what makes the difference. I think not. I will run some more tests and publish my results. Anyway, I wanted to ask what do you think. Having set up  described in my post. Do you think that is valid idea?

Comment: If in both cases the `docker-compose.yml` files are in directories named `docker`, Compose by default will think they're "the same" in ways that would cause problems for you.  (But my expectation would be that the second `docker-compose.yml` would replace the first one, not that it'd be silently lost.)  You shouldn't need to specify `container_name:`; Compose will pick a unique name on its own.

Comment: @Robert your change to networks section is 100% required. As you can see here: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/ , containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by IP addresses and thus you need to use a user-defined network to use container_name in your apache config to contact the application.

Comment: @DavidMaze - I now understand what you mean. I think that you are right about that. It worked on my Mac but on droplet on the second server I get 502 and it's complaining about `webapp` container which only exists in on the first instance, it's like first one replaced the second one. I am not sure how is that happening but I will try to play around with that and i will let you know. As for the container name I think I did that when I was learning and I wanted to use it just for the sake of trying it out.
@akazuko - thanks for confirming. That's helpful, I am learning a lot!

Comment: @DavidMaze looks like you were right but I think it worked the other way around. Somehow the first one replaced the second one. Is this expected behaviour or it is a bug? I thought that compose looks at that like completely different things because they are in different folders - "application1" and "application2"? Do you know where I can get more information on that? Finally it worked fine on my droplet by the looks of it but I had to kill everything, then rename the folder and only then I could start both instances again. It looks like docker is very moody when it comes to changes.

Comment: @akazuko Docker Compose creates a "user-defined" bridge network named `default` for you; inter-container networking works normally with no `networks:` sections anywhere in the `docker-compose.yml` file.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) has more details.

Answer (score 1):

Most important thing, you don't actually need to rename anything except for the external (host) ports and should be able to reuse same docker-compose file by using namespacing. Namespacing is achieved via --project-name (or -p) flag in compose. And compose command with it would be done as following:

```
docker-compose -p customprojectname1 up -d
```

Here your **customprojectname1** essentially establishes namespace - change it to something else for your 2nd instance etc. Again, you would still have to change host ports, as those would conflict, but nothing else should.

Regarding, your original solution with renaming everything - most likely your issue is with volumes that you forgot to rename in v2:

i.e. for mysql you have mount point set to **mysql** below:

```
mysql2:
container_name: mysql2
image: mysql:latest
ports:
  - 13309:3306
volumes:
  - mysql:/var/lib/mysql:cached
```

Which is your old mysql volume - from old stack (not renamed). Same with redis. So it needs to be mysql2 and redis2. Again, rather than doing that, go with namespacing solution I mentioned above.

Last thing, make sure to check container logs for each of the spawned containers in case they would have more clues.